# Medieval city with extreme size and population

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, cities, construction

Assume there is a medieval city with *100 million souls* inside. Let's ignore the questions why they wanted to build such a city.

In next given conditions, could this city be possible?

1. the world follows basic physics rule.
2. There is a magic that enables construction of building with a maximum height of 1,600 meters and underground 500 meters. (And I mean *construction*, not maintaining)
   The Magic might be the knowledge how to build the city and a plan for the city
3. The city should be built with pre-17th century technologies.
4. Unlimited workers and resources provided.
5. Yes, there should be infrastructures like water supply, market, harbor, etc.
   (Please don't say things like *Build human wall* or *Build a house with gold coins* kind of stuff.)

**P.S.**

I mean *possible* within the meaning of maintenance of buildings and the city itself. I don't care about Law and Order or if half of city just die within a year.

The city will be enclosed by a wall, and its size should be less than 8,000 square kilometers.

Comment: Is it a medieval city because it is enclosed by a wall? How much land would it cover? All of California is a population of 38 million. You'd need a phenomenal amount of farm land to support 100 million urban people.

Comment: That is **not** a medieval city. Medieval cities don't have buildings one mile tall. 100 million is more than the entire population of [Europe during the Middle Ages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_demography). During the High Middle Ages (11th to 13th century) Europe had 60 to 70 million people. At that time the largest medieval European city was Constantinople which had some 200 to 300 thousand inhabitants. P.S. "Magic" is not a "pre-17th century" construction technology. Either you have magic or you have medival construction tech; they are not the same.

Comment: the statement `there is magic that enables construction of building with maximun height of 1,600 meters...` goes against the next statement of using only pre 17 century tech. If something allows you to build such buildings, like magic, why would you use technology that gets 150 meters at its best?

Comment: According to economic theory unlimited money and workers is not realistic. USSR tried to achieve a state where resources are abundant during all its 80 years of existence so people would not need money. After 80 years they had less resources than countries that never tried to achieve unlimited resources (USA, West Europe)

Comment: As @EmilioLiaño notices height will be the main problem, because of materials and technologies limitations. With 10 story buildings (about 30m height) they can host about 30 million people on the territory (8000km) - based on some of the current cities. Those buildings can be built with 17-th cent tech. (materials bricks and cement). So you really do not need building that high - but if it is the requirements they are 1600m height (and not up to 1600m height) - hm, is the brilliant bricks supplier included?

Comment: 100,000,000 people on 8,000 km² means an average population density of 12,500 people per km². To put this figure in perspective, Singapore is [the third most densely populated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_territories_by_population_density#Main_table) country or territory on Earth today, at about 5,600,000 people on 719 km² which works out to an average population density of about 7,800 people per km². What you propose is another 60% more densely populated. The two more densely populated each have a population of less than 1M. Only twelve are denser than 1,000 per km².

Comment: If they have unlimited resources they can do whatever they want no?

Comment: Of your conditions, 1 contradicts 2 and 4. 2 contradicts 3 (well, it doesn't QUITE contradict 3, but the moment your kilometre-tall building was supported purely by pre-17th century technology, rather than by magic, it would probably collapse unless you built it like a pyramid with little living space inside), but partially supports 4 (create as many golems as required). I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for here. I'm guessing you're thinking in terms of a medieval fantasy version of Bladerunner Los Angeles. I don't see how it would be considered medieval, rather than magical.

Comment: Suppose there was a Chinese city with dimensions of 4 x 6 miles and population of 100,000 or 4,166.66 per square mile.  To have a population of 100,000,000 or 1,000 times it would have to have dimensions 31.622 times as great or 126.4911 by 189.732 miles or a total of 23,999.409 square miles.  Or 24 square miles by a thousand gives a total of 24,000 square miles,

Comment: Suppose that 1,000 4 x 6 mile cities were arranged in a hollow rectangle of 251 x 251 cities 1004 miles north and south and 1506 miles east and west. The inner side of the rectangle of cities would be an empty space 996 miles north and south and 1,494 miles east and west. 1,488,024 square miles of farmland.  To support 1,000,000 people each square mile of farmland would need to support 67,203.217 people. is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the most important limiting factors for the size of cities is the amount of food that can be produced. Aztec city Tenochtitlan used very advanced agriculture method chinampas and achieved the population of the biggest cities in Europe at that time (200 thousand people). In years before 1900 even after industrial revolution most of the population of Europe was still employed in agriculture. Currently the biggest aglomeration is Tokyo with 37 Mln people. So even now 100 Mln is on the limit of current technologies.

There are also other technologies that limit the population:

1. Fresh water
2. Medicine (disease is spread faster in cities)
3. Transportation (you cannot go to work of the trip to work lasts more than 3 hours)

There are probably other technological limitations.

So the answer whether the city is possible depends on the strength of magic. Without magic a medieval city of 100 Mln people is not possible.

Comment: ...Also sewage removal..

Comment: "Currently the biggest aglomeration is Tokyo with 37 Mln people. So even now 100 Mln is on the limit of current technologies." - there not a lot of countries which population is above 100 million people and usually they have enough territory and no incentive to concentrate the population in one place. So, I would not say that 37 is the limit for our technology. It definitely can be used as an example of the biggest city, but it is not the limit.

Comment: You are right that now 37 Mln is not really limited with current tech and the food is less limiting now than it was before. But I heard that in Tokyo people have very little flats that are extremely expensive and they feel that the city is crowded and they are unhappy about it. So I think with 100 Mln people it would be extremely crowded.

Comment: As OP is not caring about the happiness of those people it's not a concern.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it would probably be possible.

Apart from food issues, the magic would clear the rest.
I think in a scenario, where you can build such superstructures, they might even be held together by that magic.

And even issues like feeding everybody might not make a huge difference, as the infrastructure (especially the harbor) could be so big that the city just buys everything as they have unlimited amounts of money.

So all in all: 
A city like that would be possible, although every structure would be held together using magic.

PS: By the way, even the money problem could be (at least partially) solved if the city was some kind of giant marketplace with high taxes.